# SlickNav menu doesn't move, prependTo doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, slicknav

I have slicknav on my Wordpress theme but it stays on top of the page. I tried editing the prependto, but still it doesnt move. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="logo-wrap">logo html</div>
<nav class="main-nav"></nav>
<div class="mobile-nav"></div>
<div id="hello">this is where I want the slick nav to appear</div>`
```

Here's the JS:

```
;(function ($, document, window) {
    var
    // default settings object.
    defaults = {
        label: 'MENU',
        duplicate: true,
        duration: 200,
        easingOpen: 'swing',
        easingClose: 'swing',
        closedSymbol: '&#9658;',
        openedSymbol: '&#9660;',
    //prependTo: 'body',
    prependTo: '#hello',
    parentTag: 'a',
    closeOnClick: false,
    allowParentLinks: false,
    nestedParentLinks: true,
    showChildren: false,
    brand: '',
    init: function () {},
    open: function () {},
    close: function () {}
},
mobileMenu = 'slicknav',
prefix = 'slicknav';
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.slicknav_btn { position: relative; display: block; vertical-align: middle; float: right; padding: 0.438rem 0.625rem; line-height: 1.125rem; cursor: pointer; }
.slicknav_menu  .slicknav_menutxt { display: block; line-height: 1.125rem; float: left; }
.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon { float: left; margin: 0.188rem 0 0 0.438rem; }
.slicknav_menu .slicknav_no-text { margin: 0; }
.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon-bar { display: block; width: 1.125rem; height: 0.125rem; -webkit-border-radius: 1px; -moz-border-radius: 1px; border-radius: 1px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); }
.slicknav_btn .slicknav_icon-bar + .slicknav_icon-bar { margin-top: 0.188rem }
.slicknav_nav { clear: both; }
.slicknav_nav ul, .slicknav_nav li { display: block; }
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_arrow { font-size: 0.8rem; margin: 0 0 0 0.4rem; }
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item { display: block; cursor: pointer; }
.slicknav_nav a { display: block; }
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item a { display: inline; }
.slicknav_menu:before, .slicknav_menu:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.slicknav_menu:after { clear: both; }
.slicknav_menu { *zoom: 1; } 

.slicknav_menu { font-size: 13px; font-size: 0.8125rem; }
.slicknav_btn { margin: 0 5px; text-decoration: none; background: #9EB058; }
.slicknav_menu .slicknav_menutxt { color: #fff; font-weight: bold; }
.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon-bar { background: #f5f5f5; }
.slicknav_menu { border-top:1px solid #DCDCCD; border-bottom: 2px solid #9EB058; }
.slicknav_nav { font-size: 16px; font-size: 1rem; font-weight: 600; color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 20px; }
.slicknav_nav, .slicknav_nav ul { list-style: none; overflow: hidden; }
.slicknav_nav ul { padding: 20px 0 0 15px; border-top: 2px solid #DCDCCD; }
.slicknav_nav ul ul { border: 0; padding: 0 0 0 15px; }
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item { padding: 5px 10px; margin: 2px 5px; }
.slicknav_nav a { padding: 5px 10px; margin: 2px 5px; text-decoration: none; color: #4F4322; }
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item a { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item:hover { background: #9EB058; color: #fff; }
.slicknav_nav a:hover { background: #9EB058; color: #fff; }
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_txtnode { margin-left: 15px; }
```

How do I move the slicknav menu?

Comment: please check is there any error in console??

Comment: there is no error. the slicknav menu appears and works properly, except that it appears on top of the page. I want it to move below the `main-nav`

Comment: then you have to check css

Comment: i tried editing the css, it still doesn't move.

Comment: without url can't do anything

Comment: here's the url [link](http://labs.ratchetweb.com/). I also added css code above. But you can check the url instead. Thank you.

Comment: where you want to move this

Comment: where you want to move this at hello text??

Comment: yes, i want to place in the hello text

Comment: @VasimVanzara, do you know how to move it?

Comment: sorry,I can't move it I have to check